# Change behavior of n/N after # in vim?

Tags: vim

After I use <kbd>#</kbd> to search word under cursor in reverse order, I could use <kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd> to navigate, but it is a little confuse to use <kbd>n</kbd> for navigation in reverse order, especial after I stay a while in the code, I must try to recall I used <kbd>#</kbd> or <kbd>*</kbd>. Could I make <kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd> to be consistent in order?

Comment: It *is* consistent. `n` says "continue in the same direction". `N` says "continue in the opposite direction". It works exactly the same for `/` and `?`.

Comment: Consistent may not be a good word here. I mean 'n' for forward and 'N' for backward navigation, then it depends on less context to remember.

Comment: 1. There's no such thing as `Shift+#` or `Shift+*`. 2. `/?*#` are good for navigation but not for actual searching. Use `:ilist` or `:vimgrep` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the behavior of `n` / `N` consistently (i.e. also for `?pattern` searches), you can use the following:

```
noremap <expr> n 'Nn'[v:searchforward]
noremap <expr> N 'nN'[v:searchforward]
```

Alternatively, my [SearchRepeat plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4949) provides (among other goodies) a `g:SearchRepeat_IsAlwaysForwardWith_n` configuration that allows the same.

Answer (score 3):

I'm happy with the default behavior, as @Amadan says is kind of consistent.

Anyway if you want to change, something like:

```
:nnoremap # *NN
```

Should do the trick.
So when you hit <kbd>#</kbd> it will search forward and then go back.

More maps will be needed to keep it consistent, <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> and <kbd>?</kbd> for example.

Comment: Lol, beat me by 15 seconds :)

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what <S-#> is for you, in my keyboard `shift+#` == `~`, which is unrelated.